# Sql consulta de 20 en 20 registros

Tags: mysql, sql

Quisiera hacer una consulta de solo 20 registros de una tabla, y despues ejecutar la misma consulta pero me trajera los siguientes 20 registros
Alguna idea?

Comment: bueno para empezar que indiques que gestor de bases de datos usas y posterior que muestres tu avance

Comment: Bienvenido. Antes de todo, como dice @element, se necesita ver tu avance ya que tenemos que partir de tu código, tu pregunta también está basada en opiniones, lo más probable es que siga juntando votos negativos y  hasta tal vez lo cierren si no lo editas. Date una vuelta por [ask]. Con respecto a lo que deseas hacer, si se supone que haces la misma consulta siempre te debería dar los mismos datos. No deberían cambiar. Lo que al parecer quieres hacer es muy similar a la devolución de los datos para una páginacion. Se necesitaría más información para sacar dudas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que usas MySQL. Para realizar esto puedes utilizar limit.
Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM MiTabla limit 20
```

Te devolverá los primeros 20 registros que encuentre.

```
SELECT * FROM MiTabla limit 20 offset 20
```

Saltará los primeros 20 registros y te devolverá los 20 siguientes.

Comment: Hola Alvaro, aunque la respuesta sea la correcta según el OP, desde el [help] nos aconsejan no responder a este tipo de preguntas mal formuladas: _No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real_ ya que no muestra ni siquiera que ha intentado, ni que errores ha tenido ni un ejemplo verificable.